# Update a table with records in a sequential order

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Let's say I've got a list of Clients and I want to allocate them to a bus. I've got John, Ringo, Paul..... and they can travel on the Pink or green bus. The idea is that the allocation would be

```
John: Pink
Ringo: Green
Paul: Pink
```

Does anyone know how to do this without resorting to a loop statement?

```
--DROP TABLE [BusAllocation]
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[BusAllocation]
(
    [ClientName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [BusAllocation] [varchar](50) NULL
);

INSERT INTO BusAllocation([ClientName]) VALUES('John');
INSERT INTO BusAllocation([ClientName]) VALUES('Ringo');
INSERT INTO BusAllocation([ClientName]) VALUES('Paul');
INSERT INTO BusAllocation([ClientName]) VALUES('Simon');
INSERT INTO BusAllocation([ClientName]) VALUES('Tyrone');

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Bus]
(
    BusName [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
);

INSERT INTO [Bus](BusName) VALUES('Pink');
INSERT INTO BusAllocation([ClientName]) VALUES('Green');
```

Comment: Use `ROW_NUMBER() over` to assign an ordinal. Map the ordinal to a bus via a case statement or mapping table then update based on the ordinal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code demonstrates the basic technique. Hopefully the real tables have some unique field that can be used to provide an order in place of the `( order by ( select NULL ) )` hacks.

Note that the code generates numbers for each row independent of any other data. It will not get tripped up by gaps in identity values, e.g. when rows are deleted or transactions are rolled back.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @BusAllocation as Table ( ClientName VarChar(10), BusAllocation VarChar(10) );
insert into @BusAllocation values
  ( 'John', NULL ), ( 'Ringo', NULL ), ( 'Paul', NULL ), ( 'Simon', NULL ), ( 'Tyrone', NULL );
select * from @BusAllocation;

declare @Bus as Table ( BusName VarChar(10) );
insert into @Bus values
  ( 'Pink' ), ( 'Green' );
select * from @Bus;

-- Mix and match the buses and output the result.
with
  NumberedBuses as (
    select BusName, Row_Number() over ( order by ( select NULL ) ) - 1 as RN
      from @Bus ),
  NumberedClients as (
    select ClientName, Row_Number() over ( order by ( select NULL ) ) - 1 as RN
      from @BusAllocation )
  select NC.RN, ClientName, BusName
    from NumberedClients as NC inner join
      NumberedBuses as NB on NB.RN = NC.RN % ( select count(42) from NumberedBuses )
    order by NC.RN;

-- Do it again updating the table.
with
  NumberedBuses as (
    select BusName, Row_Number() over ( order by ( select NULL ) ) - 1 as RN
      from @Bus ),
  NumberedClients as (
    select ClientName, Row_Number() over ( order by ( select NULL ) ) - 1 as RN
      from @BusAllocation )
  update @BusAllocation
    set BusAllocation = NB.BusName
    from @BusAllocation as BA inner join
      NumberedClients as NC on NC.ClientName = BA.ClientName inner join
      NumberedBuses as NB on NB.RN = NC.RN % ( select count(42) from NumberedBuses );

 select * from @BusAllocation;
```

Comment: Wow wow wow. That is amazing HABO. I'm so very thankful for your help with my problem. Just the amount of time that you spent working on it. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

It is confusing to most of us here why you are not using Id columns. But, if it is as simple as you are saying, this would be the minimum code to achieve what you want.

```
DECLARE @RowIndex int = 0

UPDATE BusAllocation
SET BusAllocation = CASE WHEN @RowIndex % 2 = 0 THEN 'Pink' ELSE 'Green' END, 
@RowIndex = @RowIndex + 1
```

I suspect when you go to the next step you will realize the value of  identity columns and put one on each of the tables. There would then be a Client table, Bus table and BusAllocation table. The BusAllocation table would have a ClientId and BusId column and that is how you assign a bus to a client.

Comment: This is a very elegant solution - I have never seen that technique of iterating a variable within a set operation.

Comment: For reference - this technique is indicated in the MSDN documentation here:  https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177523(v=sql.105).aspx#ColumnValues
Thanks @JBrooks.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you wish to allocate clients on an alternating basis to Pink and then Green bus - this isn't clear from your question.

Can you add an auto-incrementing column to a Client table and then use module division by 2 with an update statement?

The Client table would something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Client (
    ClientId INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    ClientName varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

The first update statement would look like this:

```
UPDATE BusAllocation
SET BusAllocation = 'Green'
WHERE ClientName IN (SELECT ClientName FROM Client WHERE ClientID % 2 = 0)
```

A second update statement would then similarly be `UPDATE BusAllocation SET BusAllocation = 'Pink' WHERE ClientName IN (SELECT ClientName FROM Client WHERE ClientId % 2 = 1)`

If you want to be very strict, you might want to avoid this selecting column being the PK - just add an auxiliary column.

Comment: Thanks all for your responses. Let me clarify a little more. The tables that I have given are not my problem tables. I've just boiled the problem down to as simple as possible. Can't hard code pink or green. The reason why there is another table with values is so we could add something like purple as a bus. As for primary keys it's a test case.. Anyone got any mind bending ideas?